# Python 3 Maximizing application on launch

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok been beating my head against the wall on this one. This has been asked a few times and answered many times. However, in my situation those fixes are not working correctly and desperately need some help. Here is what Im working with; Raspberry pi 3, python 3.4.

The issue is when use the code to maximize the app upon launch, two windows open!! Arhg!!! A completely blank window opens up full screen and my app also opens but is untouched. Im sure there is something stupid Im missing but I have been beating my head against the wall for a few days now haha.

Here is my full code any help would be very greatly appreciated!!

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk



LARGE_FONT=("Impact", 12, "bold")
class TESOSapp (tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Thrive Energy Systems")
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        


        self.frames = {}

        for F in (SystemRun, ManualRun, SystemSettings, Diagnostics):


            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(SystemRun)


    def show_frame(self,cont):
            frame = self.frames[cont]
            frame.tkraise()

class SystemRun(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.grid(rowspan=8, columnspan=4)



        label = tk.Label(self, width=100, height=1)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=4)

        #Menu
        Menu1=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                        font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="SYSTEM RUN", bg='dark gray', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemRun))
        Menu1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        Menu2=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="MANUAL RUN", bg='dark gray', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ManualRun))
        Menu2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        Menu3=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="SYSTEM SETTINGS", bg='dark grey', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemSettings))
        Menu3.grid(row=1, column=2)
        Menu4=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="DIAGNOSTICS", bg='dark gray', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Diagnostics))
        Menu4.grid(row=1, column=3)

        label = tk.Label(self, width=100, height=1)
        label.grid(row=2, columnspan=4)


        #Buttons

        CycleRun=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=2,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                           text="CYCLE RUN", bg='darkorange')
        CycleRun.grid(row=3, column=0)
        CycleRun=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=2,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                           text="SERVICE MODE", bg='darkorange')
        CycleRun.grid(row=4, column=0)
        CycleRun=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=2,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                           text="AUTOMATIC OVERIDE", bg='darkorange')
        CycleRun.grid(row=5, column=0)
        CycleRun=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=2,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                           text="SYSTEM SHUTDOWN", bg='darkorange')
        CycleRun.grid(row=6, column=0)




class ManualRun(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.grid(rowspan=8, columnspan=4)

        label = tk.Label(self, width=16, height=1)
        label.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

        #Menu
        Menu1=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="SYSTEM RUN", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemRun))
        Menu1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        Menu2=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="MANUAL RUN", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ManualRun))
        Menu2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Menu3=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="SYSTEM SETTINGS", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemSettings))
        Menu3.grid(row=0, column=2)
        Menu4=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="DIAGNOSTICS", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Diagnostics))
        Menu4.grid(row=0, column=3)





class SystemSettings(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.grid(rowspan=8, columnspan=4)


        label = tk.Label(self, width=16, height=1)
        label.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)


        #Menu
        Menu1=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="SYSTEM RUN", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemRun))
        Menu1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        Menu2=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="MANUAL RUN", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ManualRun))
        Menu2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Menu3=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="SYSTEM SETTINGS", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemSettings))
        Menu3.grid(row=0, column=2)
        Menu4=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="DIAGNOSTICS", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Diagnostics))
        Menu4.grid(row=0, column=3)




class Diagnostics(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.grid(rowspan=8, columnspan=4)


        label = tk.Label(self, width=16, height=1)
        label.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)


        #Menu
        Menu1=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="SYSTEM RUN", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemRun))
        Menu1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        Menu2=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="MANUAL RUN", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ManualRun))
        Menu2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Menu3=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="SYSTEM SETTINGS", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemSettings))
        Menu3.grid(row=0, column=2)
        Menu4=tk.Button(self, width=16, height=1,
                         font=("Impact", 12, "italic", "bold"),
                        text="DIAGNOSTICS", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Diagnostics))
        Menu4.grid(row=0, column=3)




root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
root.wm_title('Thrive Energy Systems')
app= TESOSapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you with your question, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to recreate your issue with a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Tk() twice, therefore you get 2 windows. Since your TESOSapp class inherits from Tk, you can treat it as root. So the easy fix is to change the bottom to this:

```
app=TESOSapp()
app.attributes('-zoomed', True)
app.wm_title('Thrive Energy Systems')
app.mainloop()
```

In my opinion the better fix is to always inherit from Frame, never Tk.

```
class TESOSapp (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)

app= TESOSapp(root)
```

Comment: You are awesome sir!! It worked it did pull up in a single window. However, I did get an error "name 'root' is not defined "  the line its referencing is the ( root.attributes('-zoomed', True) is there a quick fix to that?

Comment: I tried the other method and still get a similar error 'root' is not defined

Comment: Ok I think im getting closer. I made the other adjustments you recommended and had to remove the title code. I still have the " root = tk.Tk() and that keeps the errors away. Now when I run the code I get a full window but it is blank. So hopefully there is just something missing that is supposed to tie it all together.

Comment: I meant for you to get rid of `root=Tk()` and everything else with "root". Since your class subclassed Tk, you now use it *instead of* `Tk()`, and you use "app" instead of "root". From your OP, delete the last 5 lines and replace them with the 4 lines I gave you.

Comment: Ok us noobies can be a little hard headed sometimes. I changed the tk.Frame back to tk.Tk use app in the lower section of code and low and behold it worked!!! Well I hope this puts a smile on your face because I can even begin tell you how grateful I am that you got me through this. Thank you!! Cheers!! Now to get to work and find new things to beat my head against!!! :)